# this.setState does not seem to be called on react native iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am currently using setState in my react-native app to render a screen.

Below is the code, for some reason the code runs everything normally except
setting the state.

```
showCard(event) {

  const { loadCard } = this.state;
  this.setState({ loadCard: true });

  console.log(loadCard)
  // get value of marker ID
  const markerID = parseInt(event.nativeEvent.id);
  console.log(markerID)
  if (markerID <= this.state.markers.length && markerID != null) {

    setTimeout(() => {
      //USE THIS FORMAT
      this.scrollView.getNode().scrollTo({ 
         x: markerID * (CARD_WIDTH), 
         animated: true 
      });

    }, 0.01);

    console.log(this.scrollView)

  }

}
```

Advice on this matter will be greatly appreciated, as it works on android for me

Comment: How exactly do you figure the `setState` command doesn't run?

Comment: I have been logging the state of loadCard which is what i use as a pre-requisite to render the component i need.

Comment: Even if `setState` where synchronous, which it isn't, your `console.log(loadCard);` logs the previous state. Even if you wrote `console.log(this.state.loadCard);` instead, it would still log the previous state. `setState` is asynchronous; calling it will change the state at an arbitrary point in the near future *after* the rest of your `showCard()` function runs.

Comment: So: when that function is called, the order of things happening is: 1. all the console.logs run 2a. the view scrolls 2b. this.state.loadCard is set to true (2b might happen before 2a)

Comment: Are you sure that `this` refers to what you want to refer? Maybe you need to `.bind(this)` where you call your `showCard` function.

Comment: @oma it works on android, and if `this` referred to something else, `this.setState` would cause an error.

Comment: Maybe try on IOS to simplify the function. Leave only the `setState` .. go step by step to debug it. From my point of view your code seems ok.

Comment: when u use ur `showCard()` so understand batter what the problem occurs and use `this.setState({ loadCard: true }, () => console.log(this.state.loadCard));` instante get update value in call back function.

Comment: hi guys thanks for the feedback, I have used the form as shared, however the state  still seems to remain false for some reason. As it works on android that puzzles me the most currently

Answer (score 0):

It does work but setting state is asynchronous so you can't just log the result after, observe with the following change:

```
this.setState({ loadCard: true }, () => console.log(this.state.loadCard));
```

The second argument is a callback fired after state is set, but you very rarely need that in reality.

Also setTimeout delay is an integer representing milliseconds not a floating point. If you want it as soon as possible use `0`.

Comment: Hi Domnic, thank you for the feedback. I have checked as well for each line and used the above method which you have shown. However for some reason the state remains as false, which puzzles me as it is working on android. could this be a dependency issue by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your functions in the constructor while settling the state

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    loadCard : false; 
  }
   this.changeCard =  this.changeCard.bind(this);
}

changeCard = (userId) => {
   this.setState({ loadCard: true});
}

render(){
   return(
       console('working state'+ this.state.loadCard);
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have somehow solved the issue. The main cause apparently as I was working with react-native maps dependency, it could not register the input directly from the marker component and required the method to be called in the main map.
But thank you for all the input guys!